# Perl: Check if string is valid directory, case SENSITIVE

Tags: windows, perl, strawberry-perl

So I have run into an issue. The -d switch will check if a directory exists just fine. However, I need it to be case sensitive. If I have directory Users, and I do if -d "UsErS", it will return true. I need it to only return true if the case matches.

Any help is much appreciated.

Code:

```
if (-d $cmdLine[1]) {
        chdir $cmdLine[1];
        print "CD: Successfully changed directory.\n";
} else {
        print "CD: Error: $cmdLine[1] is not a valid directory.\n";
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot combine `-d` with `eq`?

Comment: @TLP What do mean? How exactly would you do that?

Comment: `-d` will be as case-sensitive as the filesystem, so unless the filesystem is NTFS or (V)FAT, it's likely to behave as you want.

Comment: @RogueBukkitDev I mean `if (-d $file and $file eq 'Users')`. Or if you need to generate the name, you could do `$file eq ucfirst(lc($file))`. I am inclined to agree with mojo's answer and say that there is no possible way this is the right answer to your problem. If the file system is case-sensitive, `-d` does what you want. If it is not, there is no way that two files with the same name, but different capitalization can exist in the same directory. So... this is likely an XY-problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only definitive source for the file name is the filesystem itself. This snippet lists the entries in the parent of the target directory and verifies that the name specified matches exactly with one of those entries. I tested in from Linux on a remote NTFS share (mounted with CIFS).

```
use File::Basename;

$target = shift;
($base,$parent) = fileparse($target);

opendir($PARENT,$parent)
    or die("Error opening '$parent': $!");
%entries = map { $_ => 1 } readdir($PARENT);
closedir($PARENT);

if (-d $target && exists($entries{$base})) {
    print("'$target' exists (and correct case)\n");
} else {
    print("'$target' does not exist.\n");
}
```

I can't conceive of how you could experience this problem outside of a case-insensitive filesystem (e.g. NTFS, (V)FAT, others?), and the problem with them (at least when Windows is the OS managing it) is that you cannot necessarily guarantee that the case of the filesystem entry is what you want it to be. For example, try to rename an NTFS file changing only the case. In Windows, the file name doesn't get changed. You'd have to change it to something different entirely, then change it back to the old name with the correct case. There are (or were) configurable Windows settings that do special things if the file name is all uppercase.

Another thing to consider is that if the filesystem is case-insensitive, then there's no possibility that there could be two entries in the same directory that differed only by case. I just don't understand what useful contingency this check would account for.

Answer (score 2):

Check [`Win32`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32#Win32::GetLongPathName-PATHNAME) module,

```
use Win32;

if (-d $cmdLine[1] and $cmdLine[1] eq Win32::GetLongPathName($cmdLine[1])) { .. }
```

You may also need `use File::Spec::Functions 'canonpath';` if you want to normalize directory separators (`/` into `\` on win32)

Answer (score 0):

What TLP is suggesting is to combine both `-d` and `eq`. Something like:

```
if (-d $dirname && $dirname eq "Users"){
....
}
```

BTW `-d` alone is working fine for me. It's case sensitive. Try the below code and modify $dir to any directory which exists in your system.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $dir = "/pathto/code";
if(-d $dir){print "DIR: $dir";}
else{print "$dir is not a directory";}
```

Comment: But the thing is I'm not sure what the directory name is going to be. It might be Users or Server or anything.

Comment: Could you share your code, because `-d` is case sensitive, I've checked.

Comment: What mojo has suggested in comment is correct. Unless the filesystem is NTFS or (V)FAT `-d` will work case-sensitively. Check mojo's answer on how to handle such case.